# Cron trigger to run at half past the hour every hour

Tags: cron, triggers

Can anyone suggest a way to set a Cron trigger to run at half past the hour every hour?

So far, I've got one working hourly as per "0 0/60 * * * ?".

Am I looking at "0 0/30 * * * ?" at all?

Mr Morgan.

Comment: Which cron are you testing these with? According to crontab(5) in a Debian stable system 30 and 60 aren't allowed in the hour field.

Also there is no need to use the step (0/30) value for such a simple entry.

Answer (score 18):

I would use `30 * * * *` to run a command half past every hour.

It is worth remembering that in crontab you define a pattern to match the current time against and not an exact time. Every minute crond will awaken and match the current time against your pattern and if there is a match, run your command.

Comment: So should 60 * * * * be used to run a job hourly?

Comment: Not exactly. You would use 59 * * * * * to run a job at the last minute of every hour. I highly recommend taking a look at man 5 crontab.

Comment: Using Chron as implemented in Quartz in Java on Windows.

Comment: And here I thought you were talking about cron on Unix :) Quartz looks like it could be use full, thanks for mentioning it.

Answer (score 3):

I recommend using http://www.cronmaker.com/ for painless cron expressions.

Comment: This is interesting, but I didn't see any way of specifying the question's spec in the ui (e.g. every hour, on the half hour)

Comment: Not sure if it has changed since @UpTheCreek 's comment but you can click the hourly tab and specify a start time on the half hour.

Comment: I tried as @Kiee says, but seems to be bugged. The '5 Next Scheduled Dates' will show daily runs not hourly.

Answer (score 2):

Use this:

- 0 0/30 * * * ?

and not "30 * * * *" as this will trigger in every 30 seconds.

Comment: i don't think this is correct https://crontab.guru/every-hour-at-30-minutes

Answer (score 0):

I know this was asked years ago but the correct cron syntax for half past trigger will be:

- 30 * 1/1 * ? *

Comment: Is the bullet an asterisk that got interpreted as mark down?